# Share angular app web pages on telegram

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, telegram

I want to share a link of my angular web app on telegram with a friends, and I want telegram application to show a preview of my page as stated [here](http://telegram.wiki/tips:websharing). I did exactly what the link says but it seems the sharp sign in the URL to my site my website cause's this problem. Any idea how to solve it?
I also activated `$$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to remove sharp sign from the urls, but it just removes sharp sing after page is loaded and the address to a specific page has still sharp sign
Here is what I mean by sharing on telegram:
[image: Sharing a link on telegram with preview]

Comment: What's your back-end platform & language? (ASP.NET MVC, PHP, ...)

Comment: In html5Mode U must define a (*) route on server side

Comment: @MBN Server side code is java, spring boot framework

Comment: did you found any solution? I have same problem :(

Comment: @ShirinAbdolahi In server side, I made an API that returns a simple HTML page with the proper header elements being used by telegram. I mean the solution is not solvable by Angular, I ended up with a server-side solution